# How to use DateTime with SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-server-ce

How should I be using c# datetime values in my C# queries?

Up until now I've been doing the following:

```
Datetime my_time = new DateTime(2012, 09, 05);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", my_time);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date = @date";
```

Which has been working fine until this morning when I've been getting null errors when retrieving values from the results set.

I changed my date parameter to grab the short date string from my datetime value like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", my_time.ToShortDateString());
```

And it appears to be working fine again.

***What is the correct way of doing this?*** Obviously I'm converting my datetime value to a string, only (presumably) for the database to convert it back to a datetime before evaluating my equality where clause, which seems a little pointless.

Edit:

I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition and the date field in my example has a precision setting of 8 (date, excluding time right?). Does that mean I was passing the full date with 00:00:00.000 on the end before? How might I pass a datetime value to the database without including the time, without converting to a string first?

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just try with `my_time.Date`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", my_time.Date);
```

Comment: This is what I needed - I was most the way there on my own, but thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass it as a string or will run in troubles with culture formatting.

Try using `SqlDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not converting the date to a string - AddWithValue knows it is a date, but it is a `datetime`, so it has a time component. Do your sales have a time component to them?

```
 SELECT * FROM sales WHERE DateDiff(d, @date, date) = 0
```